# Deleting list value if there is another value after

Tags: python, list, xlrd

I have an excel file with many lines of data, but also many blank spaces. The main problem is that I have my regular average for one day's data on top of my weighted average followed by many blank spaces to the next day. So when I pull it out using xlrd I get a very messy array.

I think I know how to get rid of the blank spaces, but my list has some data that no weighted average for that day. So I need to search my list and delete any value that does not have a space after it, then search back through the list and delete all the spaces.

For example I want this:

```
[754, 753.554, '', '', '', '', '', 653.455, '', '', 258, 235.6464, '' , '', '']
```

to return:

```
[753.554, 653.455, 235.6464]
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> l = [754, 753.554, '', '', '', '', '', 653.455, '',
         '', 258, 235.6464, '' , '', '']
>>> filter(None, [i for i, j in zip(l, l[1:] + ['']) if j == ''])
[753.554, 653.455, 235.6464]
```

Comment: This did it!, is there any way I could reverse this to grab the regular average before it?

Comment: @TallnGinger Not sure what are you asking? What do you want to reverse and to what?

Comment: I think I figured it out, I wanted to grab the regular average instead this time to compare. So I was trying to turn your code around, I was confused, but I think I'm good now

`filter(None, [i for i, j in zip(row31, row31[1:]) if j != ''])`

Comment: @TallnGinger OK, if you say so :) But just beware that `zip(row31, row31[1:])` will skip the last element of the list since the second argument to the `zip` function has one element less than the first. That is why I did `l[1:] + ['']`.

Comment: so to avoid that I'd want `filter(None, [i for i, j in zip(row31, row31[1:] + ['']) if j != ''])` or should I put it on the `row31'?

Comment: @TallnGinger It depends on what do you want to do with the last number :) Last number does not have anything after it so if you wan't to include it in the result use `row31[1:] + [0]` (or anything that's not `''`) if you wan't to discard it, use `row31[1:] + ['']`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is enough:

```
data = filter(None, [754, 753.554, '', '', '', '', '', 653.455, '', '', 258, 235.6464, '' , '', ''])
```

Assuming that `weighted average` will be floating numbers:

```
filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, int),filter(None, a))
```

But you can also replace `lambda x: not isinstance(x, int)` with a function:

```
def is_not_weight_avg(x):
    # do stuff here
    # if it is w. avg.
    return x
```

and then you can write the above line as:

```
filter(is_weight_avg,filter(None, a)).
```

This is a little bit of functional programming in Python. Explanation:

```
b=range(1,11)

def is_odd(x):
   if x % 2:
      return 0
   else:
      return x
filter(is_odd, b)
>>> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: @ViktorKerkez, you are right, if you understand that `754`, is a data point without weighted average after it.